# Observing object and associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, observer-pattern, rails-activerecord

How can I perform an action based on whether an associate object has been added or removed?

Each user in my system has a profile on an external service. The profile tracks some of the user's fields. When one or more of these fields is updated on my system, I call the service to update the profile. The call is expensive, so I only want to make it when necessary.

Each user can have a pet, represented as a field in the user. The service profile for the user has a flag representing whether or not the user has a pet.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :shoe_size
  attr_accessible :unimportant_field1, :unimportant_field2
  has_one :pet
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe User

  def after_create(user)
    Service.post_user(user)
  end

  def after_update(user)
    if changed(user)
      Service.put_user(user)
    end
  end

  def changed(user)
    user.name_changed? || user.shoe_size_changed? || user.pet_changed?
    # But there is no pet_changed? method!
  end
end
```

A user might acquire a pet like this:

```
user.build_pet
   # or
user.pet = Pet.new
user.save!
```

or like this:

```
pet = Pet.create :user => user
```

Problems:

- There is no `user.pet_changed?` method; `ActiveRecord::Dirty` doesn't track associations.
- If the user gets a pet like in the second code fragment above, the user's observer isn't fired. I could observe the pet separately, and just update the pet field of the user's profile. But if I have observers on both pet and user, then in the first code fragment, which will fire first? If the pet fires first, do I do a POST or a PUT?

I'm looking for a good pattern to follow. Maybe I'll have to invent it myself.

Comment: Try this: http://anti-pattern.com/dirty-associations-with-activerecord ... any good?

Comment: @micapam that is a different scenario. The correct answer here is to user the `changed?` method on the pet. Instead of `user.pet_changed?` use `user.pet.changed?`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `user.pet_changed?`, use `user.pet.changed?`.

Comment: what I'm trying to capture is when a pet appears or disappears. The object itself changing may be another issue, but mostly I need to know when user.pet goes from nil to non-nil & vice-versa. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes. One thing you could do is just Observe the Pet model. If you only care about the case that the User modifies the pet, then you can use the `new_record?` method to check if the pet is new. So you can do `user.pet.new_record?`. Similarly, you can use `destroyed?` to check if an object has been destroyed. I have never used destroyed, so your mileage may vary. Check out the API for ActiveRecord::Persistence: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence